# Grooveshark apps on Ubuntu

Tags: software-recommendation, rhythmbox, multimedia, grooveshark

What applications are available for Grooveshark in Ubuntu, I'm in need of one that supports media keys.

Being generally "pretty" would be a plus too.

What I really want is a plugin for Rhythmbox but that does not seem to be available. So the next best thing would be something that works close to Rhythmbox.

Comment: Did you check out Clementine. But I am not sure about the media key support. Try it out.

Comment: It does feature Media Key support, and it does everything i want, please add this as an answer, so i can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out **Clementine**, Amarok-inspired music player.

Clementine provides very good UI and good search features. It does provide support for multiple internet radios like Grooveshark, lastfm, Spotify etc..

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:me-davidsansome/clementine
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install clementine
```

For more download options, check out http://www.clementine-player.org/downloads

Comment: This works but people will need a "Grooveshark Anywhere" (paid $9.00 US Dollars a month) account in order to enjoy such features in Clementine.

Comment: Yes. People need "Grooveshark Anywhere" account .

Comment: Well I added that info as a comment as you didn't mention it. Just for reference. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

also Nuvola Player has Grooveshark as one of there main internet radio providers.
here is there website http://nuvolaplayer.fenryxo.cz/home.html

Comment: It doesn't quite provide what i am looking for, and with the new webapp functionality it's not hugely useful. But it's still a valid answer.